# tree graph - find how many pairs of vertices, for which the sum of edges on a path between them is C

Tags: algorithm, graph

I've got a weighted tree graph, where all the weights are positive. I need an algorithm to solve the following problem.

How many pairs of vertices are there in this graph, for which the sum of the weights of edges between them equals C?

I thought of a solutions thats `O(n^2)`

For each vertex we start a DFS from it and stop it when the sum gets bigger than `C`. Since the number of edges is `n-1`, that gives us obviously an `O(n^2)` solution.

But can we do better?

Comment: Is the graph directed?

Comment: Yeah, there's an O(n polylog n + k) divide-and-conquer algorithm to find k pairs.

Comment: The title says "find", but the question body asks "how many" - which is it? Do you want to find all of them, or just a count of them?

Comment: (O(n polylog n) for "how many?".)

Comment: What's the solution for how many?

Comment: The ingredients are (i) the O(n)-time algorithm to find how many pairs in A x B sum to C, where A and B are sorted arrays and C is your constant and (ii) the fact that, for every n-vertex tree, there exists a vertex whose removal leaves subtrees of size at most n/2, applied recursively.

Comment: If one is careful, then I believe that the polylog n term can be simply log n.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat But you have more than two children?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, you need to ternarize. No biggie.

Comment: There is another approach: Root the tree and do a pre-order traversal. Now subtrees are represented by contiguous ranges in the traversal order. You can now do a DFS on the tree and maintain an array D of distances to the current node using the following two operations: (1) add a constant to all the numbers in a range (2) count the number of C's in the array. Those can be provided by a segment tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an undirected graph, in terms of theoretic asymptotic complexity - no, you cannot do better, since the number of such pairs could be itself `O(n^2)`.

As an example, take a 'sun/flower' graph:

```
G=(V[union]{x},E)
E = { (x,v) | v in V }
w(e) = 1 (for all edges)
```

It is easy to see that the graph is indeed a tree.

However, the number of pairs that have distance of exactly 2 is `(n-1)(n-2)` which is in `Omega(n^2)`, and thus any algorithm that finds all of them will be `Omega(n^2)` in this case.

Comment: The question is about counting though

Comment: @NiklasB. The editted question is, not the original one... (or the original title to be exact)